# Branching strategy for release based db project

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, design-patterns

We have a asp.Net vb.net 2008 project on tfs2010. The project has one main branch and for any release we create a new feature branch which is finally deployed. Post production deployment we merge back the branch back into main branch.

We are now also adding a db project to manage our SQL too. Question is how to version control the differential scripts. The db project contains all create scripts which is fine if we had to deploy thep project from scratch but the project is already live. So now any new release or hotfix would normally contain alter or change script practically.

Any ideas how to best manage both the create scripts and per release change scripts?

Comment: You need to learn more about database projects. Those are not create scripts, and you're not missing any change scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The way that we have been doing this for years is through the use of update database scripts which can update the database from a specific version to another.

There are two types of update scripts that we apply: table changes and data changes.

The table changes are recorded by hand as they are made and are designed in such a way that the script can be safely run multiple times against the same database without error. For example, we only add a column if it doesn't already exist in the table. This approach allows this version-specific script to be used for applying hotfixes as well as upgrading from one version to the next. The hotfixes are simply applied as additional entries at the end of the file.

This approach requires developer discipline, but when implemented correctly, we have been able to update databases that are 4 major revisions and 4 years out of date to the current version.

For the data changes, we use tools from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com), specifically [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

As far as the database programmability (stored procedures, triggers, etc), we keep one script that, when executed, drops all of the current items and then re-adds the current versions. This process is enabled by using a strict naming convention for all programmability elements (stored procedures are named starting with s_prefix_, functions with fn_prefix_, etc).

To ensure the correct script versions are applied, we added a small versions table (usually 1 row) that is stored in the database to record the current version of the database. This table is updated by the table update script when it is applied. We also update this table in the script that is applied to create the database from scratch.

Finally, in order to apply the scripts, we created a small tool that reads the current version of the database and a manifest that specifies which scripts to apply based on the current version of the database.

As an example:

Assuming that we have issue two major versions, 3 and 4, there are two update scripts, update_v3.sql and update_v4.sql. We have one initial structure script, tables.sql, and one programmability script, stored_procs.sql. Given those assumptions, the manifest would look something like:

tables.sql       > when version = 0
update_v3.sql    > when major_version <= 3
update_v4.sql    > when major_version <= 4
stored_procs.sql > always

The tool evaluates the current version and applies the scripts in the order specified in the manifest to ensure that the database is always updated in a known manner.

Hopefully this helps give you some ideas.